# Masking sensitive information in node

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, typescript

I want to mask/hide only json values not keys.
For Ex:-

```
myObject = {"Name":"value1","Phoneno":"545454545445"}
Output should be like below:
myObject = {"key1":*****

***,"key2":*****}
```

Can you please tell me, how we can do this in nodejs?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
let myObject = { "Name": "value1", "Phoneno": "545454545445" };
let output = {};

function mask(value: string) {
    let maskedValue = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        maskedValue += "*";
    }

    return maskedValue;
}

Object.keys(myObject).forEach(key => {
    output[key] = mask(myObject[key]);
});

console.log(output); // Object {Name: "******", Phoneno: "************"}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20myObject%20%3D%20%7B%20%22Name%22%3A%20%22value1%22%2C%20%22Phoneno%22%3A%20%22545454545445%22%20%7D%3B%0Alet%20output%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20mask(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20maskedValue%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%20i%20%3C%20value.length%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20maskedValue%20%2B%3D%20%22*%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20maskedValue%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AObject.keys(myObject).forEach(key%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20output%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20mask(myObject%5Bkey%5D)%3B%0A%7D)%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(output)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Object%20%7BName%3A%20%22******%22%2C%20Phoneno%3A%20%22************%22%7D))

Comment: Thanks , it is working. but what if JSON is like below

Comment: Like below? Below what? I don't understand

Comment: Does this work in typescript as well?

Answer (score 7):

Use maskdata npm module : https://www.npmjs.com/package/maskdata

It provides features to,

1. Mask Phone Number
2. Mask Password
3. Mask Email
4. Mask JSON fields
5. Mask Card number
6. Mask a value from the string

In your case, you want to mask JSON fields. Use,

```
const maskJSONOptions = {
  // Character to mask the data. Default value is '*'
  maskWith : "*",
  // Field names to mask. Can give multiple fields.
  fields : ['password', 'firstName'] // It should be an array
};

const obj = {
  password : "IKnowNothing",
  firstName : "Jon",
  lastName : "Snoww"
};
const maskedObj = MaskData.maskJSONFields(obj, maskJSONOptions);

//Output : { password: '************', firstName: '***', lastName: 'Snoww' }
```

I was also facing trouble with masking the data. So I published this npm module.

**You can also mask the nested objects with maskdata module.**

eg:

```
const MaskData = require('./maskdata');

const maskJSONOptions = {
 // Character to mask the data. Default value is '*'
 maskWith : "*",

 // It should be an array
 // Field names to mask. Can give multiple fields.
 fields : ['level1.level2.level3.field3', 'level1.level2.field2', 'level1.field1', 'value1'] 
};

const nestedObject = {
 level1: {
   field1: "field1",
   level2: {
     field2: "field2",
     level3: {
       field3: "field3",
     }
   }
 },
 value1: "value"
};
const maskedObj = MaskData.maskJSONFields(nestedObject, defaultJSONMaskOptions2);

//Output : {"level1":{"field1":"******","level2":{"field2":"******","level3":{"field3":"******"}}},"value1":"*****"}
```

Comment: It will not work for the nested fields like ARRAY[*].FIELD1.FIELD2
Any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you would find useful the library https://github.com/tcdl/json-masker which allows you to do this:

```
const mask = require('json-masker');
const myObject = {"Name": "value1", "Phoneno": "545454545445"};
const masked = mask(myObject); // will produce: 
                               // {"Name": "xxxxx*", "Phoneno": "************"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another competitor: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mask-sensitive-data

> Mask sensitive data eg. write debugging data to log files, etc. Supports the below-mentioned items:
>
> - credit card numbers
> - emails
> - JWT tokens
> - phone numbers
> - UUIDs

Answer (score 0):

The following strategy uses a `for...in` loop to traverse the object, replacing all property values with a chain of asterisks.

```js
const myObject = {"Name": "value1", "Phoneno": "545454545445"};

const mask = obj => {
  const masked = {};
  for (let key in obj) masked[key] = "*****";
  return masked;
};

console.log("original:",    myObject );
console.log("masked:", mask(myObject));
```

If you want the masked values to be asterisks, but the same length as the original (instead of a constant length), change the `for...in` loop to the following: `for (let key in obj) masked[key] = "*".repeat(obj[key].length);`.

**UPDATE: masking nested objects (and even arrays)**

In your comments, you asked about masking values in nested objects.

In order to process a nested object, or even a combinations of objects and/or arrays in any kind of nested arrangement, you will probably need recursion. In short, if the current value is a primitive value (e.g. a string, a number, a boolean, etc.) then replace it with the dummy string, but if the current value is an object itself (or an array), then re-send that value back into the masking process from the beginning.

The following example shows one way that that might be done. I have used jQuery to detect whether or not a value is a plain object or an array. In this example, object property names end with "A", "B", "C", etc. Arrays are converted to objects, e.g. `["foo", "bar"]` would be converted to `{"0": "*****", "1": "*****"}`.

```js
const myObject = {propA: "a", propB: {propBA: "ba", propBB: "bb"}, propC: ["c0", "c1"], propD: {propDA: "da", propDB: {propDBA: "dba", propDBB: "dbb"}, propDC: ["dc0", "dc1"]}, propE: ["e0", {propE1A: "e1a", propE1B: "e1b"}, ["e20", "e21"]]};

const mask = objOrArr => {
  const masked = {};
  for (let key in objOrArr) {
    const val = objOrArr[key];
    if ($.isPlainObject(val) || $.isArray(val)) {
      masked[key] = mask(val);
    } else {
      masked[key] = "*****";
    }
  }
  return masked;
};

console.log("original... ",    myObject );
console.log("masked... ", mask(myObject));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use a placeholder which has exactly the object's value length. Using a static placeholder would be better, in my opinion. Since it's masked, it doesn't matter how long the value is anyway.

Comment: @Vernon, Fair enough. Change the code to `for (let key in obj) masked[key] = "*****";`. Makes it even simpler. ...Incorporated your suggestion into my answer.

Comment: Thank you all but what if obect is like below:     let myObject ={
                Header: {
                    ID: "1234",
                  Name: "XYZ",
                    Username: "abc",
                    domain: "R",
                    Source: "abc",
                    MessageVersion: "1.0",
                    SendDateTime: date
                },
                Customer: {
                    Event: "1234"
                }
        };

Comment: You will probably need recursion. See the update to my answer.

Comment: This solution works but the problem here is - it will destroy the original JSON structure. The original JSON structure has nested arrays and objects while the parsed one is flat with just key-value pairs